# sequelize database error with no error message

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

It's my first time using PostgreSQL and I'm creating a REST API that using sequelize for postgresql, expressjs and nodejs.
I created a user and each user has many parcels. I am now creating a parcel which belongs to a user using userId as reference. I keep getting the database sequelize error and it has no message. It's routine says, 'checkInsertTarget'.

**Error message**

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 190,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "42703",
        "position": "48",
        "file": "d:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\parser\\parse_target.c",
        "line": "1033",
        "routine": "checkInsertTargets",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO \"Parcels\" (\"id\",\"name\",\"delivered\",\"presentLoc\",\"destination\",\"description\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"userId\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Shoe',false,'Onitsha','ESUT','black shoe, size 34','2018-11-25 15:48:13.100 +00:00','2018-11-25 15:48:13.100 +00:00','3') RETURNING *;"
    },
    "original": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 190,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "42703",
        "position": "48",
        "file": "d:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\parser\\parse_target.c",
        "line": "1033",
        "routine": "checkInsertTargets",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO \"Parcels\" (\"id\",\"name\",\"delivered\",\"presentLoc\",\"destination\",\"description\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"userId\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Shoe',false,'Onitsha','ESUT','black shoe, size 34','2018-11-25 15:48:13.100 +00:00','2018-11-25 15:48:13.100 +00:00','3') RETURNING *;"
    },
    "sql": "INSERT INTO \"Parcels\" (\"id\",\"name\",\"delivered\",\"presentLoc\",\"destination\",\"description\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"userId\") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Shoe',false,'Onitsha','ESUT','black shoe, size 34','2018-11-25 15:48:13.100 +00:00','2018-11-25 15:48:13.100 +00:00','3') RETURNING *;"
}
```

**Parcel migration code**

```
 'use strict';
    module.exports = {
      up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable('Parcels', {
          id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
          },
          name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          },
          delivered: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
          },
          presentLoc: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          },
          destination: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          },
          description: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
          },
          createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          },
          updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          },
          userId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            references: {
              model: 'Users',
              key: 'id',
              as: 'userId',
            }
          }
        });
      },
      down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('Parcels');
      }
    };
```

**Parcel model code**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Parcel = sequelize.define('Parcel', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    delivered: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    presentLoc: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    destination: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});

  Parcel.associate = (models) => {
    Parcel.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
  };
  return Parcel;
};
```

**Parcel controller**

```
const Parcel = require('../models').Parcel;
const joiSchema = require('../joischema/parcelSchema');
const validator = require('../joischema/validator');

module.exports = {
    create(req, res) {
        const data = {
            name: req.body.name,
            description: req.body.description,
            destination: req.body.destination,
            presentLoc: req.body.presentLoc,
            userId: req.params.userId,
        };
        const valid = validator.isValid(req, res, joiSchema, data);
        if (valid != null){
            res.status(500).send(valid);
        }else{
            return Parcel
                .create(data)
                .then(parcel => res.status(201).send(parcel))
                .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you inspect your database manually? Error code 42703 means "undefined column". Check your database and verify that these columns all exist.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the database and found a column which I thought I'd removed. I had to run db:migrate again to incorporate my changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the database and saw a column that I thought I'd removed. I had to run `sequelize db:migrate:undo` and then `sequelize db:migrate` again to incorporate my changes i.e. removing that column.